# Is there a good DirectX (3D) DirectWrite tutorial somewhere?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm refactoring some of my directx10 code to directx11 and trying to figure out DIrectWrite for my text functions. From MSDN, I hear that they're switching everything to this and that directwrite is now included with direct3d. But, eh - I can't find a tutorial that actually shows 3d Rendered text with directwrite. Anyone know an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft "Direct3D and Direct2D text overlay sample" should do the trick ! http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-Direct3D-Interop-ee641e46

Comment: Does this technique work without Metro/Win8?

Answer (score 2):

You want to start with the code Samples that Microsoft provide: 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DirectWrite

These are really good and I managed to implement DirectWrite quite easily following the samples. They are all documented pretty well. Check out the header file `DWrite.h` as well, this is fully documented (the same as the website).

Comment: Keep in mind - those tutorials are 2D...

Comment: The tutorials are 2D, but they can still be used in 3D. DirectWrite breaks down the API into 3 layers. Font Enumeration, Glyph Layout and Glyph Rendering. You can pick and choose the sections you want. I currently use a Direct2D renderer, but you could easily swap that for a Direct3D renderer.